# Host usb application not recognizing my usb devices?

Tags: usb-host-mode

I ran Chainfire's [USB host diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics) in my tablet. After completing the diagnostics, I got the following results:

```
  KERNEL
  claims support             yes
  device detected            no
  VERDICT
  os support                 no
  3rd party apps             no
```

If this is the result in my tablet, can I get the list of USB-connected devices through USB host applications running in my tablet?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

This result indicates that your device claims to support USB host mode, but that it doesn't actually work.

There are 6 reasons I can think of that would cause you would get this result:

A. You did the test wrong and didn't plug things in at the specified time.  Try it again and follow the instructions exactly.

B. Your USB host cable is defective or is not actually a usb host cable.  Try it again with another cable or the correct cable.

C. You used an improper device (e.g. a device that tries to draw more current than the tablet can supply, like an external hard drive, rather than a flash drive) and thus the test failed as it couldn't detect the device, because the device was unable to power up successfully.  Try it again with a different device.

D. Your device claims it supports USB host mode, but due to a software bug, it doesn't work.  An update or custom ROM may fix this.

E. Your device claims it supports USB host mode, but the hardware doesn't actually support it.  You're SOL unless you can return this device to exchange it for a Real Tablet.

F. Your device is a weird piece of work regarding USB.  Some android devices (such as the HTC Incredible S) technically implement USB host mode, but they won't provide power to the attached device.  In this case, you need to provide the juice yourself, via a self-powered hub or similar.